# PollingPattern is losing missing some Data

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

We are building a Message System with the ability to Chat direct with a User. Since we are on Rails3 and upgrade on 4 is coming end of the year we are going with polling instead of streaming.

We ran into problems, propably caused by design pattern.

```
function OurChat() {
    this.timestamp = null
    var self = this
    this.init = function() {
        self.timestamp = (new Date().getTime()).toString().substr(0, 10) //rails conform
```

so then we enable the polling, where frequency is 5000ms

```
this.polling = function() {

    $.getJSON("/chat.json?t=" + self.timestamp, function(data) {
        self.set_timestamp()

        self.update_friends(data.friends)
        self.update_messages(data.messages)

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            self.polling();
        }, self.frequency);
    });        
}
```

if we write a message , we send the request to the server and display the message with the class ".temporary"

when we poll we remove the messages with the temporary classes and add the messages, the server responded, to our message-list.
and here the problem is starting.

**Example**

```
last_polling_timestamp is **1000**
[...4.5 seconds are gone...]
 -> user sends a message -> request takes whatever it takes
[..5seconds are gone..]
 -> poling is looking for messages > timestamp **1000** 
    ->  _blank result_
[..little bit later..]
 -> message is created by server, timestamp **1001**
[..5seconds are later..]
 -> poling is looking for messages > timestamp **1005** 
    ->  _blank result_
```

How are we supposed to fix this? 
My onliest idea would be to send back the ID of each message, save the ID at the .message[data-id]. then go by polling always 10 seconds in the past (so that every request should be already there). check all messages and look if its already inside of my domtree. if not -> insert it (in the correct oder). 
**is that a better approach?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We now disabled the input field as long a post-request isn't finished.